# Problem in MikTex while I'm installing mh package

Tags: packages, miktex, installing

I'm trying to install mh package with MikTex Package Manager in windows. When I try to install it, i find thid error:

```
Unknown archive file size.
```

What is the problem? I've installed also other packages today, but only mh gives me this problem

Comment: I don't see a `mh` package in my package manager, there are mhequ and mhchem and mhs. Perhaps the package has been splitted. Synchronize the package list (menu repositories) to get an up-to-date package list.

Comment: The `mh` package has been split into `mathtools` and `breqn` since last summer.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Thank you, I used latex last summer before today, and I didn't know that..

Comment: In the Package Manager, select Repository -> Sinchronize